# What is the easiest method for sending a url to an iPhone application?

Tags: ios

I'm writing an application to help me do better research when working on the iPhone. Part of that involves keeping track of/bookmarking urls to look at later.

What's the easiest way for me to send the urls I'm looking at to my application?

So far, I'm using a special email address, and a service that parses the urls out of the email and makes it available for the app on a server somewhere, but I'd like to do better if possible

Answer (score 2):

What about [push notification](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/push-notifications/index.html).  You could even go so far as to create a browser plugin to have a button push the url to your server then use push notifications to send/replicate that url to the device.

Comment: can I install browser plugins on safari on the iphone?

Comment: I thought you were sending urls to your application on the phone not vise versa.  Considering that i have never seen a plugin for the built in browse I would say its not possible but I could be wrong.